# Java RSA algorithm returning NaN during encryption

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, rsa

I am trying to encrypt a users input with RSA encryption.

Using my debug monitor in Eclipse i can see that when the code gets to powering asciiLetter with 'e' and trying to mod 'n', the 'e' and 'n' are too large a number, and are returning infinity or NaN. Any guidance on how to change this?

I changed the bitlength down from 1024 to 128 but this had no effect.

Later I need to decrypt but am trying to get this part working beforehand.

```
public class RSA {


    static int bitlength = 128;
    private static Random r = new Random();
    private static BigInteger p = BigInteger.probablePrime(bitlength, r); 
    private static BigInteger q = BigInteger.probablePrime(bitlength, r);
    private static BigInteger n = p.multiply(q);
    private BigInteger phi = p.subtract(BigInteger.ONE).multiply(q.subtract(BigInteger.ONE)); 
    private static BigInteger e = BigInteger.probablePrime(bitlength / 2, r);
    private BigInteger d;
    private static BigInteger encryptedMessage; {
        while (phi.gcd(e).compareTo(BigInteger.ONE) > 0 && e.compareTo(phi) < 0)    {
        e.add(BigInteger.ONE);        
        }
    BigInteger d = (e.modInverse(phi)); 
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)    {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter your message: ");

    String clearMsg = input.nextLine().trim(); // String clearMsg = input.next();
        System.out.println(clearMsg); // Check message trimmed

char userInputArray[] = clearMsg.toCharArray();
ArrayList<BigInteger> cipherTextArray = new ArrayList<BigInteger> (); 

for (int i = 0; i < userInputArray.length; i++) {

    int letter = userInputArray[i];
    BigInteger bigLetter = new BigInteger(String.valueOf(letter));
    BigInteger asciiLetter = (BigInteger) bigLetter;
    BigInteger encryptedMessage = pow(asciiLetter, e);
    BigInteger encryptM = encryptedMessage;
    BigInteger encryptedMessageMod = encryptM.mod(n);
    cipherTextArray.add(encryptedMessageMod);
}

        System.out.println(cipherTextArray);
}


private static BigInteger pow(BigInteger asciiLetter, BigInteger e) { 
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
```

Comment: so you are wondering why `BigInteger encryptedMessage = pow(asciiLetter, e);` does not work? ... you didn't implement pow(...)

Comment: Is this something to do with the code:
private static BigInteger pow(BigInteger asciiLetter, BigInteger e) { 
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null; 
Because i am not sure what this does, Eclipse wanted to add it in. As i say i am new to coding and am a bit stuck :(

Comment: Use `BigInteger encryptedMessage = asciiLetter.pow(e);` instead?

Comment: Just tried this... it then asks for e to be and Integer, but i believe i need this to be a BigInteger.

Comment: You need to implement `pow()` for this to work!  BTW I hope this is just for learning -- this code should never be used in  production, there are lots of security problems with it.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using BigInteger.pow(...) and then in a second step calculating the result mod n, have a look at BigInteger.modPow(...)

does both steps in one, and does not have to have a result in memory that is bigger than your memory...